# Where can I find the actual source code for the tf2 demo?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand and modify the code for http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf2

I have done roscd for all the packages that are named (around five of them as I follow the trail) and none of them have any source code. They have .launch, .msg, .xml files but no .cpp or .py files. So I am stumped in this case, and also curious about the general case. There must be something about package structure that I am missing. Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334602/where-can-i-find-the-actual-source-code-for-the-tf2-demo?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Where can I find the actual source code for the tf2 demo?

At the bottom of the page of the tutorial you link, there is this:

> Now that we have examined the turtle_tf2_demo, let's look at how to write the broadcaster ([Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29)) ([C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)) for this demo.

Following that link, we come to the *Writing a tf2 broadcaster (Python)* page and the *Create a learning_tf2 package* section states (emphasis mine):

> First we will create a catkin package that will be used for this tutorial and the following ones. This package called learning_tf2 will depend on tf2, tf2_ros, roscpp, rospy and turtlesim. **Code for this tutorial is stored [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/turtle_tf2)**.

I'm not entirely sure which "tf2 demo" you refer to, but it would seem there is at least a link to the `turtle_tf2` package.

Note that both the Python *and* the C++ sources are hosted by that same package.

> I have done roscd for all the packages that are named (around five of them as I follow the trail) and none of them have any source code. They have .launch, .msg, .xml files but no .cpp or .py files.

Packages you install using `apt` or `apt-get` (as instructed by the *Installing the Demo* section) never include source code -- or at least: it'd be rarely the case.

`roscd` takes you to the package directory, which is the directory which contains the manifest (ie: `package.xml`). For packages installed using `apt`, that is the directory in `/opt/ros/$distro/share`. Only *resources* are installed there, no binaries, libraries, headers or source code.

(I write "never", but in reality a package author can do whatever he wants, including installing source code in locations where you'd normally only find binaries. It would be highly irregular and undesirable though)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-10-07**:
Thanks... Useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two points:

- For installed packages, `roscd` takes you to the `share/` directory of the package which is where everything that's not source code will be residing. Things like C++ headers and python code will get installed according to linux filesystem hierarchy conventions beneath the overall ROS distribution directory (e.g, `/opt/ros/melodic/include` and `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`)
- Installed packages generally only include compiled libraries and executables, and not C++ source files (though maybe they should for tutorials). To see the source code, you need to either browse it online or clone it on to your machine. In this case, the code is available here: https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-10-07**:
Thanks. Useful summary!